# Slide out div not showing top margin until its fully shown

Tags: jquery, css, margin, show-hide

Ive got a div that i want to slide out on click using `.show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);` the slide reveal works fine the problem im having is that the top of the slide out div has a top margin but the top margin dose not render properly until the div is completly revealed.

Ive made a jsfiddle of the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/NaXNe/1/

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `position:absolute` to your `.slide-cont` element

```
.slide-cont      {margin:20px;position:absolute;}
```

### *[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/NaXNe/2/)*

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` to the `.slide-out`, and optionally remove the `height: 100%` (depending on where you want the scrollbar to show up). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/NaXNe/3/